# Can I pass a variable textarea id to a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, function, variables

I've run into a follow-up problem with this excellent solution:
[Select checkbox when clicking in textarea (JavaScript?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21237797/select-checkbox-when-clicking-in-textarea-javascript).

I need to apply the solution to more than one textbox in the same form. Is it possible in any way to alter the code into something like this (not working):

```
<html>
<body>
<textarea id="iamtextarea" rows="4" cols="10" onfocus="onFocusTextArea('iamtextarea');" onblur="onBlurTextArea('iamtextarea');">Enter some text in textbox</textarea>
<input type="checkbox" name="iamcheckbox"  id="iamcheckbox" checked="checked"> I am checkbox<br>
<input type="hidden" name="hiddenString" id="hiddenString" value="Enter some text in textbox">
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function onFocusTextArea(variableName) { 
  document.getElementById("iamcheckbox").checked = false;
}
function onBlurTextArea(variableName) {
  if(document.getElementById(variableName).value==document.getElementById("hiddenString").value) {
    document.getElementById("iamcheckbox").checked = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

What I want to do is to pass a variable id of the textarea to the javascript function so that I can use the same function for more than one textarea. Is that possible?

Comment: Why not assign your different text areas different IDs and just reference them through the DOM?  document.getElementById('yourTextAreaID).value ? (edit, and then pass the id to your function..?)

Comment: Yes it's possible and what you have looks correct. At least it "works" for me: http://jsfiddle.net/4n3ux/. What exactly is "not working" for you?

Comment: Wouldn't that require one function for each textarea?

Comment: My bad. Being to used to write PHP I put $ to the variables in the JavaScript. For some reason I didn't do that mistake when I posted the code here so it took a while for me to figure out what was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f6LcV/1/) here.  This takes an element and a checkboxid

```
function onFocusTextArea(checkboxId) {
    document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked = false;
}

function onBlurTextArea(element, checkboxId) {
    if (element.value === "") {
        document.getElementById(checkboxId).checked = true;
    }
}
```

Some sample HTML

```
<textarea id="iamtextareaone" onfocus="onFocusTextArea('checkboxone');" onblur="onBlurTextArea(this, 'checkboxone');"></textarea>
<textarea id="iamtextareatwo" onfocus="onFocusTextArea('checkboxtwo');" onblur="onBlurTextArea(this, 'checkboxtwo');"></textarea>

<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxone" checked="checked">Checkbox One<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkboxtwo" checked="checked">Checkbox Two<br>
```